# Rearranging logic that uses multipe foreach conditions

Tags: php

I have some code that takes an rss feed url, expands the rss link and gets the individual links inside that feed xml. After checking if a link exists, i insert it to a table if it does not exist and do nothing if it does. However my code is becoming more unreadable and one more check that requires another foreach it shall be even more unreadable.

This is the code

```
public function links_cron_job(){
    //Get Rss Links
    $this->db->select("the_link_itself");
    $query = $this->db->get_where("search_engine_links", array("link_type" => "rss"));

    foreach ($query->result() as $row){
        $url = $row->the_link_itself;
        $rss = Feed::loadRss($url);
        foreach ($rss->item as $item) {
            $this->db->where('the_link_itself',$item->link);
            $query3 = $this->db->get('search_engine_links');
            if ($query3->num_rows() > 0){
                echo 'duplicates are there';
            }else{
                $data = array(
                    'link_country' => 'usa',
                    'the_link_itself' => $item->link,
                    'link_category' => 'news_website',
                    'link_added_by' => 'admin',
                    'link_type' => 'ordinary_link',
                    'link_local_type' => 'news',
                    'link_region' => 'countrywide',
                    'link_city' => 'washington',
                    'date_added' => $item->timestamp,
                    'last_updated' => time()
                );
                $this->db->insert('search_engine_links', $data);
                echo 'no duplicates are there';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What would be another approach in doing what i am doing?

Comment: Good code indentation would help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you read and debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: Thanks,i shall indent.

Comment: I did it for you

Comment: A working solution that requires refactoring is more suitable for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally I would say, just enter a return. But in this case you still might have
work to do in the extra iterations. So in this case at least we know that we are
done with this iteration, so at least we can add a continue statement:

```
<?php
foreach ($rss->item as $item) {
   $this->db->where('the_link_itself',$item->link);
   $query3 = $this->db->get('search_engine_links');
   if ($query3->num_rows() > 0) {
      echo 'duplicates are there';
      continue;
   }
   $data = array(
      'link_country' => 'usa',
      'the_link_itself' => $item->link,
      'link_category' => 'news_website',
      'link_added_by' => 'admin',
      'link_type' => 'ordinary_link',
      'link_local_type' => 'news',
      'link_region' => 'countrywide',
      'link_city' => 'washington',
      'date_added' => $item->timestamp,
      'last_updated' => time()
   );
   $this->db->insert('search_engine_links', $data);
   echo 'no duplicates are there';
}
```